# What is the 'Hom-description'?

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, k-theory, algebraic-k-theory

I am trying to learn about the 'Hom-description' of the class group $Cl(A)$ of an  $R_K$-order $A$ in $K[G]$ where $K$ is a number field with ring of integers $R_K$ and $G$ is a finite group.

I've tried Googling the term but I haven't yet found any readable sources.

Are there any good explanations of what the Hom description is available online?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: What is $KG$? Is it $K_0(G)$? Are you asking why $K_0(R)=\mathbb{Z}\oplus\text{Cl}(R)$?

Comment: No, I meant $K[G]$ the group ring with coefficients in $K$.

Comment: I might be able to help if you could give me a better indication of what you're talking about. What type of Hom is this? What are the objects in Hom? etc.

Comment: I think the Hom group is the group of $\Omega$-homomorphisms from the group of virtual characters $R_G$ of $G$ into the idele group of $K^c$ where $\Omega$ is the absolute Galois group of $K$ and $K^c$ is an algebraic closure of $K$. I've heard that the class group of $A$ is a quotient of this group. Other than that I don't know much about it. At the moment I am not even sure of the definition of the class group of $A$.

Comment: What is the "idels group of $K^c$? So, you want something like $\text{Hom}_{G_K}(R_G,...)$, where that $...$ is whatever the "idels group of $K^c$" is.

Comment: I meant the idele group of $K^c$. I am writing from memory of what I read from an obscure journal so the details may be slightly wrong.

Comment: Are you aware of the standard way that the class group is a quotient of the idele class group? It's not that, right?

Comment: Yes I am aware of it. The class group I have in mind is not the ideal class group of $K$, although they might be related- I simply don't know. I remember reading somewhere that the class group $Cl(A)$ is the last term of a short exact sequence involving $K_0(A)$ and $\mathbb Z$ or something similar. Would you know how this might lead to a definition of $Cl(A)$?

Comment: I'm confused now. Now it does sound like you're talking about thre class group in relation to the zeroth K group, an example of which I mentioned above. What happened to the virtual characters? If $A$ happened to be the maximal order, does $\text{Cl}(A)\oplus\mathbb{Z}=K_0(A)$ fit your need?

Comment: As far as I know, $Cl(A)$ is defined to be the last term of the short exact sequence I mentioned. One question: here does $K_0(A)$ mean the Grothendieck group of some special kind of $A$-modules? If so, what kind? Anyway, as far as I can guess, the Hom description gives another characterization of $Cl(A)$.